# Water on top of sewer pump cover

Tags: plumbing, septic

I have water standing on the top of the sewer pump cover in my basement.

[image]

The sewer pump is used to pump the waste water from a full bathroom in the basement (toilet, shower, sink) up to the main sewer line exiting the house to the drainage field in the back yard (we have a private septic system). We do not have a separate sump pump, but I do not know if there is tile/piping around the foundation to funnel ground water to this sewer pump.

A few days ago we did get a strong storm that dumped a few inches of rain in ~30 minutes. During this storm I noticed that one downspout was clogged and rain running over the gutters. The storm then knocked out power for ~5 hours - we do not have battery backup for anything.

Considering this, I'm wondering if the basin for the sewer pump overflowed and this is the cause of the standing water.

Does anyone have insight on how how to troubleshoot this issue and get things fixed?

Comment: Do you know if the pump functions (and the water on the surface is just on the surface of the lid), or if the pit is full, and the pump isn't working properly?  From the picture, you might have a separate float from the pump, and can easily check and see if the pump works.  If you have the cord from the pump plugged into another cord that goes to your outlet, plug the pump directly into the outlet and confirm it's working.  You'll either hear the pump running (and should be able to hear water flowing out) which means your float is bad, or if you hear no sound, then your pump is likely bad.

Comment: I was able to split the outlets as you suggested and just plug in one. After tightening one of the clamps (water first starting blowing out at one of the connections), I was able to hear the pump running and water running through the pipes. After awhile, the water stopped running and I could only hear the pump. Sounds like the float is likely bad then?

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not. Plug it back into the float controlled outlet and run (clean) water from the bathroom this serves. You may have just pumped out what's below the normal float "off" position (which will be set to avoid running the pump dry.) If the pump runs after you run enough water, then you just have some leakage sitting on top of the pump basin as it's a low spot in the floor. If it does not run until you switch the plugs again, the float is bad.

Comment: I plugged back in the float controlled outlet and ran water from the bathroom this serves - the pump did not run. Sounds like this indicates the float is bad. I have a plumber coming in a few days to further investigate. I'll update this thread with what I learn.